# Instance method only outputs class id, not method output

Tags: ruby

I was trying to see if I could transfer an instance variable's attributes using a simple `do` statement.

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  def bark
    puts 'Woof'
    puts 'Woof'
    puts 'Woof'
  end
end

bo = Dog.new do |word|
  word.bark
end
```

Why does it return the class id instead of the function's output?

Comment: It's probably because what you did makes no sense and the block passed to `Dog.new` method isn't even evaluated, so the only thing that this piece of code returns to the console is the identifier of the new `Dog` instance, initialized by `new`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is suggested in comments, passing block to `new` statement makes no sense.

You can change your code to:

```
bo = Dog.new('Rusty', 3).tap do |word|
  word.bark
end
```

and it will bark as expected. :)

Comment: What does .tap mean?

Comment: This method is designed exactly for the situations like in your question: when it's necessary to pass an object to a block by calling some method of that object. There is a nice explanation of the method here:
https://medium.com/aviabird/ruby-tap-that-method-90c8a801fd6a